# AttributeError at /add_property 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, attributeerror

when i tried to upload images as files which shows AttributeError at /add_property
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

```
def add_property(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pro_typ = request.POST.get('pro_typ')
        pro_tit = request.POST.get('pro_tit')
        pro_for = request.POST.get('pro_for')
        rt = Property.objects.filter(Property_reg=request.session['logg'])
        for u in rt:
            if u.Property_type == pro_typ and u.Property_title == pro_tit and u.property_sell_rent == pro_for:
                messages.success(request, 'Property already exists')
                return redirect('pro_sell')
        c_b1 = request.POST.get('c_b1')
        n_c1 = request.POST.get('n_c1')
        c_f1 = request.POST.get('c_f1')
        photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(photo.name, photo)
        pk = Registration.objects.get(id=request.session['logg'])
        cdt = Property()
        cdt.Property_type = pro_typ
        cdt.Property_title = pro_tit
        cdt.Property_brief = c_b1
        cdt.Num_of_rooms = n_c1
        cdt.Price = c_f1
        cdt.Property_sell_rent = pro_for
        cdt.Property_reg = pk
        cdt.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Added property successfully')
        return redirect('pro_sell')
    return render(request, 'add_property.html')
```

```
   <td>
         <label for="photo"><b style="color:yellow;">Photo</b></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" size="10" name="photo" multiple>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and it shows the error

AttributeError at /add_property
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Local vars
C:\Users\VYSHNAVAM\Desktop\REALESTATE\landholdings\real\views.py, line 223, in add_property
fs.save(photo.name, photo)

solution for this. how can we callback multiple files

Comment: message says your `photo` variable is `None` - check out why did that happen ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)